# NullPointerException when Calling .runTransaction() from within Listener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am receiving an error that is displaying as NullPointerException on my device screen (it is not appearing in the log).

Essentially, I am calling the `.runTransaction()` method from within `.addListenerForSingelValueEvent()`:

```
    mPollsref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        mPollsref.child(d.getKey()).child(VOTE_COUNT).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                            @Override
                            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                                mutableData.setValue((long) mutableData.getValue() + 1);
                                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                            }
```

I am receiving the below error. Is it simply because I am calling `.runTransaction()` from within a listener? I cannot find what is actually `null` and how to resolve:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your transaction handler has to be able to handle being called with a null value within MutableData, so you'll need to check for that and respond accordingly.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).  In particular, the note that says:

> Note: Because doTransaction() is called multiple times, it must be
>   able to handle null data. Even if there is existing data in your
>   remote database, it may not be locally cached when the transaction
>   function is run, resulting in null for the initial value.

More specifically, in your case, you're trying to cast the null returned by `mutableData.getValue()` to a `long`.  The Java compiler internally rewrites that as calling longValue() on the object, first cast to `Long`, and that's what's causing the error message you're seeing.